# Locating GSM Cell information for any android device Using AT Commands

Tags: android, gsm, at-command, cdma

I would like to retrieve  Network information from any Android device.

I know i could use it as a modem (when connected to a PC) and then call `AT+KCELL` which is exactly what i need - yet i have no idea how to do this while a user isn't operating (IE the device is on but not in any use like telephoning or browsing)
the device.

Is this at all possible, the aim is to triangulate my location.

Thanks

Aiden

**EDIT**

```
<scan time="20120729232941" distance="50.175018457421366" >
    <gps time="20120729232922" lng="34.9510156" lat="50.49416856" alt="137.60000610351563"         hdg="308.5" spe="16.25" accuracy="4.2426405" />
    <gsmserving mcc="255" mnc="03" lac="53100" id="8512" ss="-93" act="EDGE" rxlev="10" />
    <gsmneighbour mcc="255" mnc="03" lac="53100" id="513" psc="-1" rxlev="16" act="EDGE" />
    <gsmneighbour mcc="255" mnc="03" lac="53100" id="122" psc="-1" rxlev="14" act="EDGE" />
    <gsmneighbour mcc="255" mnc="03" lac="53100" id="121" psc="-1" rxlev="17" act="EDGE" />
    <gsmneighbour mcc="255" mnc="03" lac="53100" id="8513" psc="-1" rxlev="10" act="EDGE" />
</scan>
```

So that i can extract signal strenth and neighboring towers/cells.

An application on the Market/Play Store which found a way to do this is "Open Signal"

**EDIT**

I found a simmilar query here: [How to properly triangulate GSM cell towers to get a location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329877/how-to-properly-triangulate-gsm-cell-towers-to-get-a-location)

**EDIT**

Finally i got somewhere

Dialling: *#197328640# from my Galaxy SII, under Debug Screen I get all the info i want.

**Is there some way to do this programmatically**

The GT-I9100 Baseband Processor (BP/CP) Specifications: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241

Comment: So using `LocationManager` location updates from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` is not an option for you in this case?

Comment: No unfortunately not - I require information like which ill post above

Comment: @AidenStrydom are you sure that app is really doing that, or just finding the tower you're _probably_ using based on your fine location and cell tower maps?

Comment: As far as i understand - It really is doing "that". You could check out this vid - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYvVN5dJD7A which is related to what i want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I would not post you full code, but i think you can find what you need in this sample project http://api.yandex.ru/locator/doc/dg/samples/android_sample.zip . Check `WifiAndCellCollector.java` class, `collectCellInfo()` method. I think you could find lots of useful things there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Device manufacture (i mean mobile manufacturer )should give interface and support for AT commands to give response.(from PC serial communication)